# Finding out the src IP and port associated with the socket used in sendto function

Tags: c, linux, udp

In the below function, after I use sendto() I want to know the source IP and port used for sending the message. Is it possible to find out?

```
void sendMsg(char* payload, size_t payloadLength, const char* ip6Addr, short port)
{
        int sock;
        size_t size;
        socklen_t clilen;
        struct sockaddr_in6 server_addr, client_addr;

        sock = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

        if (sock < 0) {
                perror("creating socket");
                exit(1);
        }

        memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
        server_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        inet_pton(AF_INET6, ip6Addr, &server_addr.sin6_addr);
        server_addr.sin6_port = htons(port);

        size = sendto(sock, payload, payloadLength, 0 , (const struct sockaddr *) &server_addr,sizeof(server_addr));
        if(size < 0)
                printf("Error in sending message\n");
        else
                printf("[%d] bytes written to network\n",size);
}
```

Comment: port is easy.  I don't know about source IP.  See my answer below. Why do you need the local source ip address after sending?

Comment: I have to receive a message right after sending. As the machine has multiple IP addresses, I need both the IP and port as the message will come on the same IP and port which were used to send the message. Can I bind to a particular IP address without binding to a particular port?

Comment: If you "bind" I like I show you below in my answer, then you can use the same socket for receiving as you did for sending.

Comment: I wanted to use a specific IP address for sending.

Comment: That is, if you bind to INADDR_ANY (`0.0.0.0` or `::0`), then you are effectively telling the socket layer, "listen on all adapters".  That's probably what you want.  When you bind to port 0, you are telling the socket layer, "please pick an available port for me". That's why most client UDP sockets just bind to the all zero-address (ip and port). It enables the socket to receive on all adapters and have the OS pick a port for it.

Comment: I suspect what you really want is SO_REUSEADDR flag in a setsockopt call to share a port between sockets.

Comment: If you want to send from a specific address, you have to bind the socket to that address before sending data on it.

Comment: It would be great if I can bind to a particular IP address and keep the port 0 since I can get the port used by using getsockname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you get the port.  Bind to the INADDR_ANY address (IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT). Then use getsockname.

```
sockaddr_in6 addr = {0};
sockaddr_in6 addrLocal = {0};
socklen_t addrSize = sizeof(addrLocal);
unsigned short port = 0;

addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM,0);
bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)); // bind to the INADDR_ANY address for IPV6

getsockname(sock, (sockaddr*)&addrLocal, &addrSize);

port = addrLocal.sin6_port;
```

I'm not sure about the IP address.  The IP address embedded inside the `addrLocal` will still be all zeros.  Not sure how you get the IP address used for a particular packet send.  Worst case, you enumerate the routing table to infer which interface and address are most likely to be used for particular target IP.

Comment: I did minor changes in your program. Instead of bindiing to INADDR_ANY, I binded to a given IP and 0 port. when I use getsockname, I'm getting different ports on each run, but sometimes I'm getting negative values as well! Why's that?

Comment: Of course you'll get a different port on each run.  That's how port allocations work.  I don't know how possibly can get a negative port value - especially when `port` is declared as `unsigned short`.

Comment: Thanks @selbie. you're right..I had made a mistake. I was storing the value in signed short.

Answer (score 1):

From the Linux manpage for [udp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html)

> In order to receive packets, the socket can be bound to a local address first by using `bind(2)`.  Otherwise, the socket layer will automatically assign a free local port out of the range defined by `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` and bind the socket to `INADDR_ANY`.

Unbound UDP IPv6 sockets are treated the same. So you can get the local port used by the socket after sending the first packet by using `getsockname()` as already demonstrated, but you can't get a specific local address because there isn't one - a packet sent to any of the machine's addresses on that port will be received (Modulo firewall rules etc. of course).

---

There is hope, however.

The shell command `ip route get ADDRESS` will show you the network interface and IP address used to send packets to `ADDRESS`. See [`rtnetlink(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html) for how to access the routing tables programatically.